# How to get selected text from Gmail body using gmail AddOn

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, add-on

I'm using **card services(App Script)** to make a **Gmail addon**. I want to implement functionality - If the **user selects text from the email body** I want that **selected text in my Gmail addon**.

Can anyone guide me on how to get selected text from Gmail body using Gmail AddOn?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your concern? How about this SO case : [Apps Script - Gmail addon - Get selected text in Gmail message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67819483/apps-script-gmail-addon-get-selected-text-in-gmail-message?rq=2)

Comment: Thank you! I read this case. I am clear with my doubt.